# Error while importing an Oracle 9 dump in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, oracle9i, impdp

[image]

I need to import an  Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.6.0 dump in an Oracle 11g.
Using the import command I have a ton of erros like this:

```
 IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 6550:
 "BEGIN  SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION.SET_IMP_SKIP_INDEXES_OFF; END;"
 IMP-00003: ORACLE error 6550 encountered
```

Th command I use is:

```
 imp system/<passwor>@<SID> file=export_20160209.dmp fromuser=USER1 touser=USER1 log=file_log_10022016.log
```

How else can I make the import I need?

Comment: Did the import actually work? Maybe you can simply ignore those messages.

Comment: The problem is that the import never gets to an end. It gets stuck in error messages like this that keep appearing like in an neverending loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permission to user as:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_DEFER_IMPORT_INTERNAL TO <user>;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION TO <user>;
```

Comment: I've done that, but I still have the same error on and on:

Comment: Please tell me full procedure you adopt for this? It would be best if you provide snap

Comment: sometime we may need to re-install Oracle.

Comment: I've just added a printscreen

Comment: I am using mRemote to connect to the oracle VM with an user that has all the rights. This is the procedure I always use for similar imports.

Comment: I ran them in sqldeveloper, I used SYS user to connect :

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked, so I asked for a new dump without the table where the import stopped.